# MySql's date separator in str_to_date

Tags: mysql

I allow users to enter dates as **15-10-2010** and **15/10/2010**. Problem is, I can only specify one separator type in mysql's str_to_date. So if a user enters 15-10-2010, then `STR_TO_DATE('15-10-2010','%d-%m-%Y')` would work fine. But if the user did **15/10/2010**, I get a null value in the database column. Is there a way to tell mysql to all both - and / as the seperator?

Comment: i think that you should allow only one single date format to user using mask on the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Replace function in mysql.

Something like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('15/10/2010', '/', '-'), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Hope this helps,
Arne